# How did Walt and Jesse know where to intercept Mike?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad* Season 5, Episode 1, Walt and Jesse meet Mike on a one-lane dirt track in the middle of nowhere, after Mike has learned from the doctor that Gus is dead. How did they know when and where Mike would be driving?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They don't go to that specific road to meet Mike, they are travelling to *intercept him*, as you have identified.

Mike has been at a clinic 'Safe-House' of Gus', recovering from the stomach wound inflicted in 'Salud' S04E10. **Jesse drove him and Gus there at the end of this episode.** So Jesse knows where he is.

[image]

Mike is going to kill Walt, out of revenge and possibly to remove/eliminate witnesses, thus making himself unimpeachable.

On his way out from this remote location, he meets Walt and Jesse, *who are travelling to it* in order to gain Mike's assistance in removing the camera's 'evidence' from the now destroyed lab.

Comment: Yes, I recall that Gus and Jesse had to walk six miles to the border, so presumably Jesse knows the route.